# Python GEKKO: multiple if statements do not work

Tags: python-3.x, gekko

I need to use two simple if statements in my GEKKO optimization. However, a solution is only found if only one of the statements is active - see `m.z1` and `m.z2` (under "# CONDITIONAL STATEMENTS"; lines 80-83). How can I make both statements work?

(Here is the [EViews code](https://gennaro.zezza.it/software/eviews/v6/gl05lp2.prg) I wish to translate.)

```
# https://gennaro.zezza.it/software/eviews/v6/gl05pl2.prg

from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np

# Amount of model loops
RUNS = 1

m_arr = [GEKKO(remote=False) for x in range(RUNS)]

for i in range(RUNS):
    # INITIALIZATION
    #  Model
    m = m_arr[i]

    #  Endogenous variables
    m.b_cb = m.Var(name="b_cb")  # Government bills held by Central Bank
    m.b_d = m.Var(name="b_d")  # Demand for government bills
    m.b_h = m.Var(name="b_h")  # Government bills held by households
    m.b_s = m.Var(name="b_s")  # Government bills supplied by government
    m.bl_d = m.Var(name="bl_d")  # Demand for government bonds
    m.bl_h = m.Var(name="bl_h")  # Government bonds held by households
    m.bl_s = m.Var(name="bl_s")  # Supply for government bonds
    m.cg = m.Var(name="cg")  # Capital gains on bonds
    m.cg_e = m.Var(name="cg_e")  # Expected capital gains on bonds
    m.cons = m.Var(name="cons")  # Consumption goods
    m.er_rbl = m.Var(name="er_rbl")  # Expected rate of return on bonds
    m.h_d = m.Var(name="h_d")  # Demand for cash
    m.h_h = m.Var(name="h_h")  # Cash money held by households
    m.h_s = m.Var(name="h_s")  # Cash money supplied by central bank
    m.p_bl_e = m.Var(name="p_bl_e")  # Expected price of bonds
    m.r_bl = m.Var(name="r_bl")  # Interest rate on government bonds
    m.t = m.Var(name="t")  # Taxes
    m.v = m.Var(name="v")  # Households wealth
    m.v_e = m.Var(name="v_e")  # Expected households wealth
    m.y = m.Var(name="y")  # Income = GDP
    m.yd_r = m.Var(name="yd_r")  # Regular disposable income of households
    m.yd_r_e = m.Var(name="yd_r_e")  # Expected regular disposable income of households
    m.p_bl = m.Var(name="p_bl")  # Price of bonds
    m.tp = m.Var(name="tp")  # Target proportion

    #  Exogenous variables
    m.g = m.Param(name="g")  # Government goods series
    m.r_b = m.Param(name="r_b")  # (5.23) Exogenously set interest rate on government bills
    m.p_bl_bar = m.Param(name="p_bl_bar")  # Exogenously set price of bonds
    m.add = m.Param(name="add")  # Random shock to households' expectations about bond prices
    m.bot = m.Param(name="bot")  # Bottom value for target proportion
    m.top = m.Param(name="top")  # Top value for target proportion

    #  Parameters
    m.alpha1 = m.Param(name="alpha1")
    m.alpha2 = m.Param(name="alpha2")
    m.chi = m.Param(name="chi")
    m.lambda20 = m.Param(name="lambda20")
    m.lambda22 = m.Param(name="lambda22")
    m.lambda23 = m.Param(name="lambda23")
    m.lambda24 = m.Param(name="lambda24")
    m.lambda30 = m.Param(name="lambda30")
    m.lambda32 = m.Param(name="lambda32")
    m.lambda33 = m.Param(name="lambda33")
    m.lambda34 = m.Param(name="lambda34")
    m.theta = m.Param(name="theta")
    m.beta = m.Param(name="beta")
    m.beta_e = m.Param(name="beta_e")

    #  Lagged variables
    m.r_b_lag = m.Var(name='r_b_lag'); m.delay(m.r_b, m.r_b_lag, 1)  # Interest rate on bills, lagged (t-1)
    m.b_h_lag = m.Var(name='b_h_lag'); m.delay(m.b_h, m.b_h_lag, 1)  # Bills held by households, lagged (t-1)
    m.bl_h_lag = m.Var(name='bl_h_lag'); m.delay(m.bl_h, m.bl_h_lag, 1)  # Bonds held by households, lagged (t-1)
    m.v_lag = m.Var(name='v_lag'); m.delay(m.v, m.v_lag, 1)  # Wealth of households, lagged (t-1)
    m.p_bl_lag = m.Var(name='p_bl_lag'); m.delay(m.p_bl, m.p_bl_lag, 1)  # Price of bonds , lagged (t-1)
    m.b_s_lag = m.Var(name='b_s_lag'); m.delay(m.b_s, m.b_s_lag, 1)  # Bills supplied by the government, lagged (t-1)
    m.bl_s_lag = m.Var(name='bl_s_lag'); m.delay(m.bl_s, m.bl_s_lag, 1)  # Bonds supplied by the government, lagged (t-1)
    m.b_cb_lag = m.Var(name='b_cb_lag'); m.delay(m.b_cb, m.b_cb_lag, 1)  # Bills held by central bank, lagged (t-1)
    m.h_s_lag = m.Var(name='h_s_lag'); m.delay(m.h_s, m.h_s_lag, 1)  # Money supplied by central bank, lagged (t-1)
    m.yd_r_lag = m.Var(name='yd_r_lag'); m.delay(m.yd_r, m.yd_r_lag, 1)  # Disposable income, regular, lagged (t-1)
    m.p_bl_e_lag = m.Var(name='p_bl_e_lag'); m.delay(m.p_bl_e, m.p_bl_e_lag, 1)  # Expected price of bonds, lagged (t-1)

    #  CONDITIONAL STATEMENTS
    m.z1 = m.if3(m.top - m.tp, 1, 0)  # (5.25) z1 = 1 if TP > top (y = x1 when condition<0)
    # m.z2 = m.if3(m.tp - m.bot, 1, 0)  # (5.26) z2 = 1 if TP < bot
    # m.z1 = m.Param(name="z1")
    m.z2 = m.Param(name="z2")

    #  Equations
    m.Equations([m.y == m.cons + m.g,  # (5.1)
                 m.yd_r == m.y - m.t + m.r_b_lag * m.b_h_lag + m.bl_h_lag,  # (5.2)
                 m.t == m.theta * (m.y + m.r_b_lag * m.b_h_lag + m.bl_h_lag),  # (5.3)
                 m.v == m.v_lag + (m.yd_r - m.cons) + m.cg,  # (5.4)
                 m.cg == (m.p_bl - m.p_bl_lag) * m.bl_h_lag,  # (5.5)
                 m.cons == m.alpha1 * m.yd_r_e + m.alpha2 * m.v_lag,  # (5.6)
                 m.v_e == m.v_lag + (m.yd_r_e - m.cons) + m.cg,  # (5.7)
                 m.h_h == m.v - m.b_h - m.p_bl * m.bl_h,  # (5.8)
                 m.h_d == m.v_e - m.b_d - m.p_bl * m.bl_d,  # (5.9)
                 m.b_d == m.v_e * (m.lambda20 + m.lambda22 * m.r_b - m.lambda23 * m.er_rbl - m.lambda24 * (m.yd_r_e / m.v_e)),  # (5.10)
                 m.bl_d == m.v_e * (m.lambda30 - m.lambda32 * m.r_b + m.lambda33 * m.er_rbl - m.lambda34 * (m.yd_r_e / m.v_e)) / m.p_bl,  # (5.11)
                 m.b_h == m.b_d,  # (5.12)
                 m.bl_h == m.bl_d,  # (5.13)
                 m.b_s == m.b_s_lag + (m.g + m.r_b_lag * m.b_s_lag + m.bl_s_lag) - (m.t + m.r_b_lag * m.b_cb_lag) - m.p_bl * (m.bl_s - m.bl_s_lag),  # (5.14)
                 m.h_s == m.h_s_lag + m.b_cb - m.b_cb_lag,  # (5.15)
                 m.b_cb == m.b_s - m.b_h,  # (5.16)
                 m.bl_s == m.bl_h,  # (5.17)
                 m.er_rbl == m.r_bl + m.chi * (m.p_bl_e - m.p_bl) / m.p_bl,  # (5.18)
                 m.r_bl == 1 / m.p_bl,  # (5.19)
                 m.p_bl_e == m.p_bl_e_lag - m.beta_e * (m.p_bl_e_lag - m.p_bl) + m.add,  # (5.20B)
                 m.cg_e == m.chi * (m.p_bl_e - m.p_bl) * m.bl_h,  # (5.21)
                 m.yd_r_e == m.yd_r_lag,  # (5.22)
                 m.p_bl == (1 + m.z1 * m.beta - m.z2 * m.beta) * m.p_bl_lag,  # (5.24A)
                 m.tp == (m.bl_h_lag * m.p_bl_lag) / (m.bl_h_lag * m.p_bl_lag + m.b_h_lag)])  # (5.27)

    # ASSIGN VALUES
    #  Time
    tstart = 1945
    tend = 1950
    tdur = tend - tstart + 1
    m.time = np.linspace(0, tend - tstart, tdur)  # start,stop,num

    #  Parameters
    m.alpha1.value = np.full(tdur, 0.8)
    m.alpha2.value = np.full(tdur, 0.2)
    m.chi.value = np.full(tdur, 0.1)
    m.lambda20.value = np.full(tdur, 0.44196)
    m.lambda22.value = np.full(tdur, 1.1)
    m.lambda23.value = np.full(tdur, 1)
    m.lambda24.value = np.full(tdur, 0.03)
    m.lambda30.value = np.full(tdur, 0.3997)
    m.lambda32.value = np.full(tdur, 1)
    m.lambda33.value = np.full(tdur, 1.1)
    m.lambda34.value = np.full(tdur, 0.03)
    m.theta.value = np.full(tdur, 0.1938)
    m.beta.value = np.full(tdur, 0.01)
    m.beta_e.value = np.full(tdur, 0.5)

    #   Exogenous variables
    m.g.value = np.full(tdur, 20)
    m.p_bl_bar.value = np.full(tdur, 20)
    m.r_b.value = np.full(tdur, 0.03)
    m.add.value = np.full(tdur, 0)
    m.bot.value = np.full(tdur, 0.495)
    m.top.value = np.full(tdur, 0.505)

    #  Start values
    m.p_bl.value = m.p_bl_bar.value

    m.v.value = np.full(tdur, 95.803)
    m.b_h.value = np.full(tdur, 37.839)
    m.b_s.value = np.full(tdur, 57.964)
    m.b_cb.value = m.b_s.value - m.b_h.value
    m.bl_h.value = np.full(tdur, 1.892)
    m.bl_s.value = m.bl_h.value
    m.h_s.value = np.full(tdur, 20.125)

    m.yd_r.value = np.full(tdur, 95.803)
    m.p_bl_e = m.p_bl.value
    m.tp.value = np.full(tdur, 0.5)
    m.z1.value = np.full(tdur, 0)
    m.z2.value = np.full(tdur, 0)

    # SOLVE
    m.options.IMODE = 6
    m.solve(disp=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be with something other than the m.if3() statement. Setting `m.z2 = 1` and removing `m.z2.value = np.full(tdur, 0)` gives an infeasible solution. It may be that `m.if3()` is returning the correct `0` or `1` but that when it equals `1`, there is no feasible solution. The possible infeasible equations are listed in the local run directory `m.open_folder()` in the file `infeasibilities.txt`.

```py
************************************************
***** POSSIBLE INFEASBILE EQUATIONS ************
************************************************
____________________________________________________________________________
EQ Number   Lower        Residual     Upper        Infeas.     Name
         1   0.0000E+00   5.0965E-01   0.0000E+00  -5.0965E-01  p(1).n(1).sysa1.x(1): 0 = -x_{k+1} + A(1 ,:) x_k + B(1,:) u_k
 Variable   Lower        Value        Upper        $Value      Name
        25  -1.2346E+20  -4.7965E-01   1.2346E+20   0.0000E+00  p(1).n(2).r_b_lag
         0  -1.2346E+20   0.0000E+00   1.2346E+20   0.0000E+00  p(1).n(1).r_b_lag
         0  -1.2346E+20   3.0000E-02   1.2346E+20   0.0000E+00  p(1).n(1).r_b
____________________________________________________________________________
EQ Number   Lower        Residual     Upper        Infeas.     Name
         7   0.0000E+00  -1.1379E-04   0.0000E+00   1.1379E-04  p(1).n(1).sysa7.x(1): 0 = -x_{k+1} + A(1 ,:) x_k + B(1,:) u_k
 Variable   Lower        Value        Upper        $Value      Name
        31  -1.2346E+20   1.8921E+00   1.2346E+20   0.0000E+00  p(1).n(2).bl_s_lag
         0  -1.2346E+20   0.0000E+00   1.2346E+20   0.0000E+00  p(1).n(1).bl_s_lag
         0  -1.2346E+20   1.8920E+00   1.2346E+20   0.0000E+00  p(1).n(1).bl_s
____________________________________________________________________________
EQ Number   Lower        Residual     Upper        Infeas.     Name
        12   0.0000E+00   6.4041E-01   0.0000E+00  -6.4041E-01  p(1).n(2).sysa1.x(1): 0 = -x_{k+1} + A(1 ,:) x_k + B(1,:) u_k
 Variable   Lower        Value        Upper        $Value      Name
        64  -1.2346E+20  -6.1041E-01   1.2346E+20   0.0000E+00  p(2).n(2).r_b_lag
        25  -1.2346E+20  -4.7965E-01   1.2346E+20   0.0000E+00  p(1).n(2).r_b_lag
         0  -1.2346E+20   3.0000E-02   1.2346E+20   0.0000E+00  p(1).n(2).r_b
...
```